# multiple fancybox ajax content in one page javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I have used multiple fancyboxes in one page to show ajax content.

HTML Code:

```
<a href="test.txt" class="various fancybox.ajax" data-fancybox-type="ajax" >Test 1</a>
<a href="test.txt" class="various fancybox.ajax" data-fancybox-type="ajax" >Test 2</a>
<a href="test.txt" class="various fancybox.ajax" data-fancybox-type="ajax" >Test 3</a>
```

Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".various").fancybox();

});

</script>
```

I have used jquery version 1.7.1. The fancybox doesn't open properly after two clicks. How to fix this?

Comment: _`The fancybox doesn't open properly after two clicks.`_ What does this mean? It does not open or opens after second click.

Comment: It doesn't open after two clicks. The fancy box opens fine for first two times. If i click it for the third time it doesn't open.

Comment: Your code works. My guess? there must be something on your second click (maybe coming from your ajax content) that triggers a js error so fancybox no longer works. If the files that you are pulling have scripts themselves, it might be the reason. But is just a guess, can you share a link?